# FIX market data, QuickFIX or something else?

Tags: java, quickfix

I'm looking into the possibilities to build a small JAVA application that imports real FOREX data and store it to analyze later. With this data I want to help a friend to make an algorithm. After this, the app have to also handle real transactions. Still in the orientation phase, but I do not want to waste time with implementation x and then later on find out it had to be done with implementation y.

So importing data has to be FREE, RELIABLE and FAST enough to handle future transactions based on this data.

**So far I have two options;**
1. Json requests to a third party, which I read is kinda slow, but I already have an idea of how I would implement it.
2. QuickFIX, used by many professional parties, but very new to me.

**Json question:**
Slow in a way that the data input isn't analyzed correctly and an application with algorithm has problems to work?

**QuickFIX question:**
Where do you get an account and the actual data from? I get the implementation, but it is unclear to me with what account QuickFIX works with and which parties I should look at.

So in a nutshell; what is the best way to go when I want trustworthy FREE data, which is FAST and RELIABLE enough to make transactions with?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need an account with a market data provider to get market data.
I don't know if this has changed but the last time I checked there was no access to real time market data for free. At most delayed by 15 minutes. But I do not recall if this was even via FIX protocol.

NB: you really might want to look at QuickFIX/**J** (since you are looking for a Java implementation)

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: Occasionally new entrants (exchanges or the like) offer data for "free" but often is only open to genuine client prospects. The last one to do this for Forex was Fastmatch FX which offered a free Forex stream (I don't remember which kind of API). They were acquired by the CBOE however and the option removed.